# getting hocr output from tika-server

Tags: tesseract, apache-tika, tika-server, hocr

I am doing OCR to a PDF file using Apache TIKA Server.

I am interested in the [hOCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#hocr-output) output, but only succeed to get the output in plain text format.

Following the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/TikaOCR) and the [code](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/64f0f9c59cf50e69a39a4133091021b6c3872b57/tika-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/server/resource/TikaResource.java#L147), I am trying to configure Tesseract using `X-Tika-OCR...` HTTP headers. In this case, I am using the `X-Tika-OCRoutputType: hocr` HTTP header, but I get the plain text output or html output without HOCR tags.

I tried both the `/tika` and `/rmeta` endpoints.

The `curl` commands I use:

```
curl -v -X PUT --data-binary @file.pdf \
     "http://tika-server:8081/tika" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" \
     -H "X-Tika-OCRoutputType: hocr"

curl -v -X PUT --data-binary @file.pdf \
     "http://tika-server:8081/rmeta" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" \
     -H "X-Tika-OCRoutputType: hocr"
```

I also tried setting the `Accept` header to text/plain, text/html text/xhtml and text/hocr. None works. The last one gets an error.

I am using:

- Apache Tika 1.22
- Tesseract 4.1.0-3.1.x86_64
- RedHat 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspecting the integration test code of `TikaResourceTest`, I realized an HTTP header was missing. The correct command should include the `X-Tika-PDFOcrStrategy: ocr_only` HTTP header. See more in the [ocr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR) & [pdf parser docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/PDFParser%20(Apache%20PDFBox))

The command would thus be:

```sh
curl -v -X PUT \
     --data-binary @file.pdf \
     -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" \
     -H "X-Tika-PDFOcrStrategy: ocr_only" \
     -H "X-Tika-OCROutputType: hocr" \
     "http://tika-server:8081/tika"
```